# User principal name (UPN) or mail ownership verification in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Retrieving a given user's info (specifically, for a signed-in user using the endpoint /me), we get a few fields back from the use object.
My question is, can we be sure the user is the owner of the email address under **mail** and / or **userPrincipalName** (if its a valid email address)?
Is that *guaranteed* / verified for every account?

Thanks!